# Store and read csv file from android and ios in Unity

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project which I want to work for both android and ios. I also have a csv file which I want to read during runtime. I tried the following code:

```
    string basePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"{fileName}.csv");
    if (File.Exists(basePath))
    {
        string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(basePath);


        foreach (string item in rows)
        {
            Debug.Log(item);
        }
    }
```

However, I don't know where to put the csv file for it to find it on persistentDataPath. And if I find the correct place, will it be the same on android and ios or do I need to save the file on more locations or folders?

Or do you have any other suggestions on how to store and then load a cvs for different platforms?

Comment: You cannot find a file in persistentDataPath when you release the project, you need to put the file in [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) or [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html)

Comment: I tried putting the file in StreamingAssets which seems to work. Will it work on both android and ios too and not just on my computer?

Comment: On android you need use UnityWebRequest to retrieve file from StreamingAssets.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a pain, and I assume it's another method for ios? Since the files are static I might as well print them and save them to local variables instead.

Comment: No, you may read the first link in my comment, it's just several lines.

Comment: Honestly, this seems too complicated and there is virutally no documentation on this. I just want to get a csv file from where I put it...

Comment: Do you have try that is indicate in the link in the first comment by @shingo?

Comment: @vernou, yes I tried but failed. The documentation is not clear to me and there are no good examples. How hard can it be to just read a file :P

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read a .csv file that you deploy with your game, you could just place it into the `Resources` folders inside your `Assets`.

You could read it like this:

```
TextAsset file = Resources.Load(fileName) as TextAsset;
string content = file.ToString();
```

Note: `fileName` must be specified here without file extension.

If you want to modify the `.csv` file or perhaps make it available in `Application.persistentDataPath`, you can simply copy it to that location first. For later changes you can then access the file in `persistentDataPath`.

**Self-Contained Example**

A self-contained example could look something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class CSVFileManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var fileName = "example";
        var csvFileName = $"{fileName}.csv";
        string basePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, csvFileName);
        Debug.Log($"basePath = >>{basePath}<<");
        if (!File.Exists(basePath))
        {
            TextAsset file = Resources.Load(fileName) as TextAsset;
            string content = file.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(basePath, content);
        }
        else 
        {
            //... work with the current file in persistentDataPath
        }

    }
}
```

**Test**

I tested it briefly on Mac, but it should work equally well on Android and iOS:

[image: example]